# Getting all the fields from the row with the latest "ID"

Tags: t-sql

I want to get the entire row of a table in SQL Server, but only the last inserted row (which is the row with the highest "ID"). I tried top, max etc, but can't seem to get this to work. So if the highest ID is 15, I want to get all the fields of that row (15).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this?

```
 SELECT * FROM MyTable
 WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable)
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from Table1
WHERE
  ID = ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE id = (
            SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM table
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should do it ...**

```
select top 1 *
  from yourtable
 order by id desc
```